# How to expect a property to equal a function that has appropriate name with Chai

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, chai

I'm testing some react elements with shallow rendering and I want to assure that they have the right types and children.

But when I expect the type of the object in the virtual dom to equal the element name I'm using, it turns out to be a function.

How do I expect a function?

```
it('should console log this', function(){


    tree = sd.shallowRender(React.createElement(Thing));

    const vdom = tree.getRenderOutput()

    console.log('vdom.props', vdom.type);
    expect(vdom.type).to.equal('Element');
});
```

`AssertionError: expected [Function: Element] to equal 'Element' at Context.<anonymous> (/thing/thing/thing/tests.webpack.js:100318:33 <- webpack:///src/containers/CompanyManagement/thing-test.js:38:26)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to test the name of the function? That would be `expect(vdom.type.name).to.equal('Element');`

Comment: vdom.name is undefined

Comment: Hmm, try `vdom.type.name`. What do you get when you `console.log(vdom)`?

Comment: Ah there we go, vdom.type.name is a go.

As for when I type console.log(vdom), it says `TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string`.. and when I do `JSON.stringify()` it says can't convert a circular structure. Is there any way around that?

Comment: I'm not so familiar with `Symbol`s and `skin-deep` (the renderer you seem to be using). Possibly `console.log(vdom.toString())` would work, but I'm not too sure..